# Object not found and RStudio

Tags: r

So I know this is common problem but nothing I found seems to have worked. The problem that I am having is that R keeps stating that the object isn't found even though I know it's there because it listed in the names of the df.

The code I have run so far is:

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\fredd\\Dropbox\\Grad_Life\\Spring_2017\\AFM\\Final_Paper\\")
KWTProd.df = read.csv("Merge1//Kwht_Production_07-15.csv", header=T)
names(KWTProd.df)
plot(Period_kWh_Production$Production.Period.End.Date)
```

and the console displays this:

```
> setwd("C:\\Users\\fredd\\Dropbox\\Grad_Life\\Spring_2017\\AFM\\Final_Paper\\")
> 
> KWTProd.df = read.csv("Merge1//Kwht_Production_07-15.csv", header=T)
> 
> names(KWTProd.df)
 [1] "Application.Number"                      "Program.Administrator"                   "Program"                                
 [4] "Total.Cost"                              "System.Owner.Sector"                     "Host.Customer.Sector"                   
 [7] "Host.Customer.Physical.Address.City"     "Host.Customer.Physical.Address.County"   "Host.Customer.Physical.Address.Zip.Code"
[10] "PBI.Payment.."                           "Production.Period.End.Date"              "Period_kWh_Production"                  
> 
> plot(Period_kWh_Production$Production.Period.End.Date)
Error in plot(Period_kWh_Production$Production.Period.End.Date) : 
  object 'Period_kWh_Production' not found
```

Comment: In R you need "\\" or "/". Try to change to this : `setwd("C:\\Users\\fredd\\Dropbox\\Grad_Life\\Spring_2017\\AFM\\Final_Paper\\")`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `KWTProd.df$Production.Period.End.Date` in the `plot` statement?

Answer (score 3):

Anytime R tells you that an object is not found it's not trying to play a trick on you.  In this case you are using the wrong name.  Your code shows us that `KWTProd.df` has a field called Production.Period.End.Date but then you try to access an object called `Period_kWh_Production` instead of `KWTProd.df`.

So the error is legit and it seems like you wanted to access `KWTProd.df$Production.Period.End.Date` instead.

Comment: Hmm I tried but still got the same error. To clarify I think the code I put for "KWTProd.df" is the name of the data frame I am using but in this case I am trying to display Kilowatt production over time. The name for Kilowatts produced as that the console displays is "Period_kWh_Production" but perhaps I should have given more different names idk

Comment: @FredDitzian I'm not sure what you mean when you say you tried but still got the same error. Either way this is going to get closed. You just need to be more careful and pay attention to the names you're using.  Are you saying you want to use `KWTProd.df$Period_kWh_Production` instead?

Comment: Sorry if I am not being clear enough but the name of the file "Kwht_Production_07-15.csv". I made it into a .df named "KWTProd.df" and I am trying to show changes in the variable named ""Period_kWh_Production" over time which in this case I am using "Production.Period.End.Date". I have tried "plot(KWTProd.df$Production.Period.End.Date)" and "plot(Period_kWh_Production$Production.Period.End.Date)" but both times I got the error "object 'Period_kWh_Production' not found" or "object 'KWT.prod.df' not found" in both instances. Sorry that I am not being clear enough

Comment: Well you never mentioned anything about KWT.prod.df so that makes sense.  I think you just want to do something like `plot(Period_kWh_Production ~ Production.Period.End.Date, data = KWTProd.df)`  But it just sounds like you're getting really mixed up on how to define and reference variables and that should be covered in any introductory R materials so maybe you should just do some reading?

Comment: Thanks a lot that did help. Unfortunately my time variables is formatted like "dd/mm/yyyy" such 02/12/2008 and I am trying to make yearly averages because the plot is too noisy. That being said your suggestion worked and I wanted to say thanks.